# How to get name and email value from a custom form and add it to campaign monitor subscriber list?

Tags: customization, forms

I have a custom form in my site that has name and email address field. How can I get the value of this 2 fields to be added on campaign monitor subscriber list when the user successfully submits the form?

This is my form action:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/opt/www/wp-load.php');

$articletitle = $_POST['articletitle'];
$articlename = $_POST['articlename'];
$articleemail = $_POST['articleemail'];
$articletext = $_POST['articletext'];

$org_post = array(
  'post_title'    => $articletitle,
  'post_content'  => $articletext,
  'post_status'   => 'pending',
  'post_type'     => 'post',
  'post_author'   => 6
);
$new_id = wp_insert_post( $org_post );

update_post_meta($new_id, 'contact_name', $articlename);
update_post_meta($new_id, 'contact_email', $articleemail);

header("Location: /success/");
die();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the Campaign Monitor Api:

http://campaignmonitor.github.io/createsend-php/

Or if you only use it for newsletter sign up, you can use a plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=campaign+monitor

Comment: Remove the quotes: $result = $cm->subscriberAdd($eventemail, $name);